# socket.io-client holds the running status after a while on disconnection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket)
{
    console.log("server is connected");
    socket.on('disconnect', function ()
    {
        console.log("disconnected");
    });
});
```

client.js

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')
            .connect('http://localhost:3000/')
            .on('connect', function ()
            {
                console.log("client connected");
                socket.disconnect();
            })
            .on('disconnect', function ()
            {
                console.log('client disconnected');
                //not going to finish the client.js app imediately.
            });
```

Why?

socket.io-client holds the running status about 1 minutes after the disconnect event.

Is there any fundamental fix or smart workaround?

node.js v0.8.8

socket.io v0.9.10

socket.io-client v0.9.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bug to me. If you don't want to wait you can do `process.exit()` in disconnect callback.

Answer (score 0):

I've just simply done as the follow.

client.js

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')
        .connect('http://localhost:3000/')
        .on('connect', function ()
        {
            console.log("client connected");

            process.abort();

          //  socket.disconnect();
        })
        .on('disconnect', function ()
        {
            console.log('client disconnected');
        });
```